# sql multiple column concatenation using stuff

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation, ssms-2014

i have two columns invoice status and vendor number.i want to concatenate invoice status into one row based on vendor number using stuff

```
vendor num    invoice status
70000141      V-Parked Items
70000141      V-Parked Items
70000141      not available
70000141      s-noted items
77000141      V-Parked Items
```

output should be:

```
vendor num    invoice status
70000141      V-Parked Items,s-noted items,not avilable
```

can any one help in this

Comment: Which database are you using? There are many you know.

Comment: I am using sql server

Answer (score 4):

`stuff()` is available in SQL Server so, i would do :

```
select vendor_num, stuff( (select distinct ','+t1.invoice_status
                           from table t1
                           where t1.vendor_num = t.vendor_num 
                           for xml path('')
                          ), 1, 1, ''
                        ) as invoice_status
from table t
group by vendor_num;
```

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "dbo.table4.VendorNumber" could not be bound.
this is the error i got while trying above code.table which has columns is dbo.table2

Comment: @cherry. . . Why you choose reference from `table4.VendorNumber` which is already available from `table2.VendorNumber` ??

Comment: I am a bit confused from above code what are t1 and t with that  i tried table4 what are t1 and t in above code can u please share

Comment: @cherry. . . As per your sample query `t` is a `dbo.table2 t` & `t1` is a `dbo.table2 t`` for `subquery` available in `stuff()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I am using sql management studio 2014. I tried using this code but ended up with an error:

```
select VendorNumber, stuff( (
    select distinct ','+dbo.table2.InvoiceStatus
    from dbo.table2
    where dbo.table4.VendorNumber = dbo.table2.VendorNumber 
    for xml path('')
    ), 1, 1, ''
) as InvoiceStatus
from dbo.table2
group by VendorNumber
```

But ended up with error Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3:

> The multi-part identifier "dbo.table4.VendorNumber" could not be
>   bound.

The table which have columns is `dbo.table2`.

Comment: Please do not add additional information as an answer. [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52184085/edit) your question instead.

Answer (score -1):

use `group_concat` if mysql

```
select vendo_num,group_concat(invoice_status separator ',') from tablea
group by vendo_num
```